# Difference between Post link and link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In custom directive, pre link and post link functions are there. I have understood difference between pre and post but is there any use of post function if we are not going to use pre? Like why should we use post over link function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `preLink()` and `postLink()` functions within `compile()` allows you more control over when the linking function is called.

`link()` acts a shorthand for `postLink()`.

In most cases, you would typically use `link()` over `postLink()` where all that is needed is basic DOM manipulation (very common). If, for example you needed to manipulate the model or `$scope` before it is linked with the view, the `preLink()` function is where you can do that.

It is worth noting though, that typically any issues that `preLink` tries to solve can typically be resolved by a parent controller and should be encouraged.